# Help with Statistical Analysis

Tags: analysis, statistics

I have been asked to conduct a small survey and then analyse the results of the said survey for a class project. I decided to conduct an anonymous survey of voters for the 2012 presidential elections. The Information collected was :

Age Group

Gender

Preference for Presidential Candidate

Personal Political Views (Liberal, Conservative, etc)

So I now have the data, but I am stuck as to what I can do with it. I know I can get the numbers for the voters in a state and compare them, but I need to initially present data summaries such as summary statistics or graphical displays and justify if my sample is a valid representation of the population. I fear I have taken on a bit too much and I would be very grateful for any advice as to what I can do and calculate with this data.

Comment: Are you trying to see if there is any correlation between the categories? Maybe you can group data based on age and gender then see if there is any correlation between the groups and political views.

Comment: You can find many examples to use as a model for your own data, for example Pew: http://pewresearch.org/pubs/2412/pew-research-exit-poll-analysis-2012-obama-reelection, there are many ways to chart, plot, analyze, correlate... a data set. You will choose some angles for your data and do a nice analysis and summary of that as you cannot do it all. You may even be able to put your data in something like Excel and use it's stats tools to analyze and plot results. Does this help or are you looking for more items?

Comment: I am supposed to be using minitab though I am struggling to see where I can make use of it. My sample data is only of 50 surveys so its not like I have a huge data set to play with!

Comment: You have the descriptive statistics option on Minitab that can output basic data like standard deviation, mean, median, etc. You can also use the regression option to test for any correlation.